# Python shlex - Split

Tags: python, shlex

I would like to split thanks to shlex this kind of string:

```
str = 'This doesn''t work' 54e+5 15 .FALSE. 'Another example of "test"'
```

Result expected:

- This doesn''t work
- 54e+5
- 15
- .FALSE.
- Another example of "test"

My main issue is that the syntax uses double simple quotes '' inside a quoted string.
I cannot get shlex to work. I tried the following settings:

```
lex = shlex.shlex(str)
lex.whitespace_split = True
lex.quotes = "'"
```

But it splits between the '' even if there is no whitespace character.

Thank you !!

Comment: Your `str` is not valid Python, the embedded quotes need to be escaped.

Comment: Also you shouldn't call it `str`, `str` is a builtin

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you control how the text is generated, I would write the file as a CSV and allow the csv module to properly quote the items. Then reading it back into a list would be a cinch.

But given the text as it is, how about:

```
In [4]: import shlex
In [6]: text = """'This doesn''t work' 54e+5 15 .FALSE. 'Another example of "test"'"""
In [34]: [item.replace('\\"\\"',"''") for item in shlex.split(text.replace("''",'\\"\\"'))]
Out[34]: ["This doesn''t work", '54e+5', '15', '.FALSE.', 'Another example of "test"']
```

Comment: Hello, this string is in a text file and I need to parse it. It is true that I forgot the triple quote in typing it here, sorry! And in my code the variable is not named str, of course. With shlex.split, it works but I loose the quote between doesn and 't'... Maybe I should try a replace("''", "\'")?